# Is it possible to cache mapped regions returned from MapViewOfFile?

Tags: c++, windows, linux

Good afternoon, It is a well known fact that when dealing with large files 
that cannot be mapped to one view in Win32, create code that carefully maps 
and unmaps file regions as they are needed. The pastebin url is:

I created and tested a cMemoryMappedFile class that deals with large files 
that cannot be mapped to one view in Win32. I tested the class and found 
that while it functions OK, it takes a long time(i.e 3 seconds) for 
random access. This is because the class has to unmap and map a file 
region for every random access. I was wondering if it was possible to 
cache the mapped regions returned from MapViewFile to speed up random access.

Yesterday, I noticed that UnMapViewOfFile invalidates a previously 
mapped region returned from MapViewOfFile. Does anyone have ideas 
about how to speed up random access through caching or other methods?

Currently the viewport is 128KB. I believe that if I enlarge the 
viewport it will reduce the number of calls to UnMapViewOfFile 
and MapViewOfFile. However, I was wondering if could use other 
methods. Please look at the method,
char* cMemoryMappedFile::GetPointer(int , bool) to see how the 
viewport is shifted with the file mapping. Thank you.

The pastebin url for the class is
 > . 
I am adding the source code here in case no one can access the url.

```
// cMemoryMappedFile.Cpp
#include "cException.h"
#include "cMemoryMappedFile.h"

#define BUFFER_SIZE 10

#define MEM_BLOCK_SIZE 65536 * 2

/**
\class cMemoryMappedFile
\brief Encapsulation of the Windows Memory Management API.

The cMemoryMapped class makes some memory mapping operations easier.
*/

/**
\brief Constructor for cMemoryMappedFile object.

\param FileSize    Size of file.
\param OpenMode    File open mode 
\param AccessModes File access mode 
\param ShareMode   File sharing mode 
\param Flags       File attributes and flags 
\param ShareMode   File sharing mode 
\param Flags       File attributes and flags
\param Security    Security Attributes 
\param Template    Extended attributes tp apply to a newly created file
*/
cMemoryMappedFile::cMemoryMappedFile(long FileSize_, OpenModes OpenMode_,AccessModes AccessMode_,
    ShareModes ShareMode_,long Flags_,void *Security_,FILEHANDLE Template_) {
    FileSize = FileSize_;
char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE]; 
DWORD dwRetVal = 0;
UINT uRetVal   = 0; 
     DWORD dwPtr    = 0;
BOOL isSetEndOfFile = FALSE;
     LARGE_INTEGER Distance_;
DWORD ErrorCode = 0;

char lpTempPathBuffer[MAX_PATH]; 

     PreviousNCopy = 0;
PreviousN     = 0;

//  Gets the temp path env string (no guarantee it's a valid path).
dwRetVal = GetTempPath(MAX_PATH,          // length of the buffer
                       lpTempPathBuffer); // buffer for path 
if (dwRetVal > MAX_PATH || (dwRetVal == 0))
{
   throw cException(ERR_MEMORYMAPPING,"");  
     }

     //  Generates a temporary file name. 
     uRetVal = GetTempFileName(lpTempPathBuffer, // directory for tmp files
                          TEXT("DEMO"),     // temp file name prefix 
                          0,                // create unique name 
                          TempFileName);  // buffer for name 
     if (uRetVal == 0)
     {

      throw cException(ERR_MEMORYMAPPING,lpTempPathBuffer);  
     }
     //  Creates the new file
     hFile = CreateFile((LPTSTR) TempFileName, // file name 
                       AccessMode_,        // open for write 
                       0,                    // do not share 
                       (SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES *) Security_,  // default security 
                       OpenMode_, // CREATE_ALWAYS,       
                       Flags_,// normal file 
                       Template_);                // no template 
     if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) 
     { 
       throw cException(ERR_MEMORYMAPPING,TempFileName);   
     } 
     Distance_.LowPart = (ULONG)FileSize_;
Distance_.HighPart = 0; // (ULONG)(FileSize_ >> 32);
dwPtr = ::SetFilePointer(hFile,Distance_.LowPart,
    &(Distance_.HighPart), FileBegin);

if (dwPtr == INVALID_SET_FILE_POINTER){
   throw cException(ERR_MEMORYMAPPING,TempFileName);
}
isSetEndOfFile = SetEndOfFile(hFile);
if (!isSetEndOfFile){
   ErrorCode = GetLastError();
   throw cException(ERR_MEMORYMAPPING,TempFileName);
}
hMapping=::CreateFileMapping(hFile,(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES *)Security_,PAGE_READWRITE,0,0,0);
if (hMapping==NULL)
    throw cException(ERR_MEMORYMAPPING,TempFileName);   

MapPtr = 0;
adjustedptr = 0;
prevadjustedptr = adjustedptr;

    FilePath=new char[strlen(TempFileName)+1];
    strcpy(FilePath,TempFileName);
}



char * cMemoryMappedFile::GetPointer(int n, bool Caching){
unsigned int baseoff; 
if( n < MEM_BLOCK_SIZE / 2)
{
  baseoff = 0;
}
else
{
  baseoff = ((n + MEM_BLOCK_SIZE / 4) & 
    (~(MEM_BLOCK_SIZE / 2 - 1))) - MEM_BLOCK_SIZE / 2;

}
// the correct memory mapped view is already mapped in
     if (adjustedptr != 0 && mappedoffset == baseoff && Caching)
    return adjustedptr;
else if (Caching)
{
  /*    
   retrieve adjustedptr from cache
      */
}
// get a new memory mapped viewport
else{
    if (MapPtr){
                 UnmapViewOfFile(MapPtr);
       PreviousNCopy = PreviousN;
       prevadjustedptr = adjustedptr;
    }
    PreviousN = n;
              mappedlength = min(FileSize - baseoff, MEM_BLOCK_SIZE); 

              // MapViewOfFile should be aligned to 64K boundary

    MapPtr = (char*)::MapViewOfFile( hMapping, 
                       FILE_MAP_WRITE | FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 
        baseoff, mappedlength);
              mappedoffset =    baseoff;
    adjustedptr = MapPtr - mappedoffset; 
    printf("Value: %u n: %u\n",adjustedptr[n],n);

 /*
    cache PreviousNCopy,PreviousN, prevadjustedptr[PreviousNCopy]
 */

}
 return adjustedptr; 
}
```

Comment: The pastebin url is <iframe src="http://pastebin.com/embed_iframe.php?i=ctqR4iWd" style="border:none;width:100%"></iframe> . I don't know if Stack Overflow accepts pastebin. I can remove if the code if anyone wants me to do so. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a "free list" style cache --- when the user of your class asks to unmap a region you don't really, you just add it to the list. When they ask to map a new region then you reuse an existing mapping if possible, otherwise you create a new mapping, deleting the least-recently-used one from the cache if you've got too many mappings open, or where the mapped size of the cached mappings is too large.

Comment: @Anthony Williams, I just accepted your answer. I was wondering if I use should use a time stamp to keep track of the least recently used mapping. Should I use a STL:set or STL::list for the cache? How do I determine if I have too many mappings open? Thank you.

Comment: @Anthony Williams, There are some good posts on Stack Overflow about implementing a LRU cache using Boost or STl. Thank you for answer.

Comment: @Anthony Williams, I read a link about operating system caching. Is it possible for the user to augment the operating system by implementing a least recently used cache of memory mapped views? Thank you.

Comment: @Anthony Williams, This is the link about operating system file caching. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364218(v=vs.85).aspx. Thank you.

Comment: There are many ways of doing an MRU list, as you indicate. (BTW, this question is not accepted, just upvoted). You could just use an ordered list, bringing an item to the front when it is used. The least-recently-used element will naturally just be the last element. Unless you are writing kernel drivers, you can't augment the OS, but keeping the mapping handles open will avoid the overhead of creating the mapping --- you just don't want to keep too many open or it will eat up your address space (as well as consuming the handle and associated data structures.)

Comment: @Anthony Williams, Will a most recently used(MRU) cache of memory mapped views improve random access? I know it is difficult to predict random access.

Comment: Profile it. You won't know if it works for your use case until you try it.

Comment: @Anthony Williams, I just tried to accept your answer again.The first time I tried to accept your answer the HTML popup window said something like it will take 48 seconds to accept. Then popup window vanished. Should I contact StackOverflow.com about this problem? Thank you.