# Is it possible for STL set to be faster than STL multiset for preventing duplicate entries?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, stl

Good afternoon, We are currently using STL multimap and STL set to cache memory mapped file regions. We would like our cache to have only unique entries. We wondering if there is a way for STL set and STL map to be faster than STL multiset and STL multimap for preventing duplicate entries.
      We are using the following code excerpt to prevent STL multimap and STL set duplicate entries. Is it possible to make this faster? Thank you.

```
int distance(char* x, char* y,int error){ 
    if (x >= y && (x - y) <= error){ 
        return 0;
    }
    return (x - y);
};

class MinDist {
public:
    MinDist(){}

    MinDist(char* & p, const int & error){}

    bool operator() (char *  p1, char *  p2 )
    {
      return distance( p1, myPoint, myError) < distance( p2,  myPoint, myError); 
    }

public:
    static char* myPoint;
    static int myError;
};


std::multiset<Range> ranges_type; 
std::multimap<char *,Range, MinDist> mmultimap;


MinDist::myPoint = TmpPrevMapPtr;
MinDist::myError = MEM_BLOCK_SIZE;

std::pair<I,I> b = mmultimap.equal_range(TmpPrevMapPtr); 
for (I i=b.first; i != b.second; ++i){ 
     ranges_type.erase(i->second);
     numerased++;
}

typedef std::multimap<char*,Range,MinDist>::iterator J;
std::pair<J,J> pr = mmultimap.equal_range(TmpPrevMapPtr); 


erasecount = 0;
J iter = pr.first;
J enditer = pr.second;
for(  ; iter != enditer ; ){ 
    if ((*iter).first == TmpPrevMapPtr){
        mmultimap.erase(iter++); 
        erasecount++;
    }
    else{
        ++iter;
    }
}

MinDist::myPoint = 0; 

ranges_type.insert(RangeMultiSet::value_type(n, n + mappedlength,
                &adjustedptr[n],MapPtr,mappedlength));


mmultimap.insert(RangeMultiMap::value_type(MapPtr,
                   Range(n,n + mappedlength,
                      &adjustedptr[n],
                      MapPtr,mappedlength)));
```

Comment: Ugh, soo much to read... in general, a) don't use `distance` on associative containers, and b) the implementation of set/multiset/map/multimap is virtually identical, so there's very little difference. To check if an entry already exists, just use `find` or `count`.

Comment: Performance aside, if you don't want duplicate entries, using a type that allows duplicate entries seems pretty silly.

Comment: @Kerrek SB, Thank you for your reply. We believe count() takes O(N) time and find() takes O(log N), If we use a find() or count() before every multiset and multimap insert, would that increase the cost of every insert? Thank you.

Comment: @Dennis Zickefoose, Thank you for your answer. How does one create a type that does not allow duplicate entries? Thank you.

Comment: @Frank: Belief is good, but what is `N`? `N` is the number of equal elements (not *total* number of elements), so that's a trivial difference. Set and multiset are really essentially the same. You're right of course that `find` is preferable to `count` in multisets. Beyond that, I really don't understand what you're trying to achieve; if you don't want duplicates, you can use `find`/`count` to see if the entry already exists and then act accordingly.

Comment: OK, wait, back up: I now have reason to believe that you have only very limited experience with C++, so I should like to ask you to describe what you *want to achieve* rather than discuss this particular attempt of yours. Go back as far as you can to keep the question specific.

Comment: @Frank - set and multiset are essentially the same and probably share the same code in most implementations. To insert a new element you first have to find the proper place to insert it, then decide if it is already there (set) or insert it anyway (multiset). The cost would be almost identical.

Comment: @Bo Persson, Thank you for your reply. How does one find out what multisession do? Thank you.

Comment: @Bo Persson, Thank you for your reply. We will try to use STL set instead of multiset and see if the speed is faster. Thank you.

Comment: @Kerrek SB, This Stack Overflow link describes what we are trying to achieve. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5173931/is-it-possible-to-cache-mapped-regions-returned-from-mapviewoffile. Thank you for your help and please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: @Frank: Hm, this is way too opaque and cluttered for me to see through right now. Maybe if you can abstract the problem a bit and encapsulate the API calls (which I'm not familiar with) so we can concentrate on the actual caching idea... but maybe someone else has better insights on this already.

Comment: @Kerrek SB, Thank you for your reply. This is a difficult problem because it requires understanding what MapViewOfFile and UnMapViewOf File do as well as understanding STL data structures. You are an expert on C++ and STL so I believe you can understand what MapVieOfFile and UnMapViewOfFile do. In the limited space allowed for these comments, we cannot post all the MapViewOfFile documentation we have, Thank you.

Comment: @Frank: Well, if you can abstract the file mappings into your `Range` class correctly, then we could concentrate on how to cache ranges. But since I don't know what the semantics of a range are (e.g. do they get invalidated when you create a new range), it's hard for me to make precise statements. If you feel that you can describe your problem in modular, self-contained units, feel free to ask another question.

Comment: @Kerrek SB, We just posted the definition of the Range class as a answer and how it relates to the MapViewOfFile API. When we create a new range, ideally the other ranges in the STL multiset cache are not invalidated. Our question is how do we most efficiently ensure that that all the entries in the multiset are unique? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a lot of stuff to read here, and optimization of the complex container types is a tricky problem. I've spent a fair bit of time working on similar problems, so I'll try to point out some things that have helped me.

Firstly, the usual way to make your code faster is *don't use binary trees when vectors will do*. The Microsoft STL implementation is going to spend about 14 bytes (3 pointers + short int for red/black flag last I checked) of overhead for each node in your map/set, plus malloc overhead of at least 4 more bytes before it gets around to storing your node data. While I don't know the specifics of your domain too well, memory mapped I/O strikes me as an area where there likely exists a complex but faster vector-based solution. It would require that the number of blocks you map simultaneously is small--if your lookup-table is up to or less than 6,000 bytes, a sorted-array implementation with memmove for insert/erase, and binary_search for lookup will likely be faster in Release mode (and in Debug mode, it'll be faster up to several megabytes, sadly). If the elements are 4-byte pointers, then 6,000 bytes allows for up to 1,500 mapped blocks.

There are times that you simply need to use trees, however. One case is complex nodes (so that construction/destruction is essential) or fairly high element count (so that the O(N) array insertion becomes slower than the malloc cost of O(log n) tree insertion). What can you do here? Note that map/multimap and set/multiset or pretty nearly the same speed; the multi* versions do tend to be a little slower, but only because the code to handle them is a few lines longer.

Anyway, one thing that can help a lot is figuring out how to cut the malloc cost, since every node is going to call malloc/free at some point. Cutting that is *difficult*--the Release mode allocator is roughly the equivalent of about 50-200 arithmetic operations, so while it's beatable, it takes some effort. You do have some hope, though -- map/set allocations are all identically sized, so a memory pool can work very well. [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=custom%20stl%20allocator) is probably a good way to get started; there are many good articles on this topic.

Finally, there's an open source sampling profiler that I have found very helpful -- it's called [Very Sleepy](http://www.codersnotes.com/sleepy), and usually Just Works on Visual Studio projects. If you want to definitely answer whether map/multimap or set/multiset is quicker in your case, that's the main thing I'd point you to. Good luck!

Comment: @AHelps, Thank you for your thoughtful reply. We tried converting STL trees to sorted vector. In Scott Meyers excellent book, Effective STL, Scott Meyers describes how to do this conversion. However, Scott Meyers solution is optimal for the case where you first sequentially insert into a vector. Then, Scott Meyers says to sort the vector. At this point, Scott Meyers says all accesses  to the sorted vector should be read only without any insert. What we found is that if we want to do a insert into the vector again, we have to sort the vector: cost O(N Log N). This is costly. Thank you.

Comment: @AHelps, We agree with you that a profiler is necessary. We converted our C++ Windows class into Linux and we used Callgrind and KCachegrind to profile our code. However, Callgrind runs only with gcc -g and takes 10 to 100 times longer. So when we have a large data set, it can take up to 2 days to profile the code. Thank you.

Comment: @Frank Don't resort when you insert; insertion should be O(N). Shift the vector up one element with memmove or a loop and place the item directly. Secondly, Very Sleepy doesn't have those problems. It is fast (50% of original time, typically), works on Release code, is free, and runs on Windows.

Comment: @AHelps, Thank you for your suggestions. We may have to your Sorted Vector idea. What is your opinion of using a sorted STL deque doubly linked list to emulalate a STL  instead of a sorted STL vector? I am not trying to ask a loaded question. I know there any many different opinions about this subject. Thank you.

Comment: @Ahelps, We found a Fixed Size Block Allocator suite for STL set and map.http://warp.povusers.org/FSBAllocator/. Have you heard about this one? Which memory pool allocator do you recommend for STL set and map? Thank you for your answer,

Comment: @Ahelps, We used the Fixed Size Block Allocator with max_size set to 4010 instead of 1 for a 4000 element std::set<Range> and found that that it was 2.93% slower than the standard STL::allocator. Could you think of reasons why this memory pool allocator is slower than the standard STL::allocator? Thank you.

Comment: @AHelps, I just accepted your answer. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Sorry for the complete lack of replies; apparently SO notifications and I don't get along. For the history: I believe deque is not typically better than vector for mid-array insertions. A fixed-size block allocator could, in theory, be faster, but you really do have to test; the built in malloc is sometimes pretty good too (as you discovered). I don't have a block allocator that I use regularly, so I'm afraid I'm not much help there. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a generic situation:

```
#include <cstddef>   // for size_t
#include <set>       // for std::set
#include <algorithm> // for std::swap
#include <ostream>   // for std::ostream

struct Range
{
  int start, end; // interpret as [start, end), so Range(n,n) is empty!

  Range(int s, int e) : start(s), end(e)
  {
    if (start > end) std::swap(start, end);
  }

  inline bool operator<(const Range & r) const
  {
    return (start < r.start) || (!(r.start > start) && end < r.end);
  }

  inline size_t size() const { return end - start; }
};

std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream & o, const Range & r)
{
  return o << "[" << r.start << ", " << r.end << ")";
}

typedef std::set<Range> cache_t;

cache_t::const_iterator findRange(int pos, const cache_t & cache)
{
  cache_t::const_iterator it = cache.lower_bound(Range(pos, pos)),
                         end = cache.end();

  for ( ; it != end && it->start <= pos ; ++it) // 1
  {
    if (it->end > pos) return it;
  }

  return end;
}

inline bool inRange(int pos, const cache_t & cache)
{
  return findRange(pos, cache) != cache.end();
}
```

Now you can use `findRange(pos, cache)` to discover whether a given position is already covered by a range in the cache.

Note that the loop at `// 1` is rather efficient as it only starts at the first element where `pos` could possibly be and stops once `pos` can no longer be in range. For non-overlapping ranges this will cover at most one range!

Comment: @Kerrick SB, Thank you for your answer. We will try it now and try to let you know the results either tonight or tomorrow morning, Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Frank: Cool, no worries. I added an output operator for convenient inspection and a check that the start is not larger than the end.

Comment: @Kerrick SB, I have good news for you. I tried your STL Set code on a large data set and it is 6 percent faster than STL Multiset. Now I will try AHelps memory pool suggestion using the Fixed Size Block Allocator suite for STL set and map http.warp.povusers.org/FSBAllocator. Should we convert the STL multimap mmultimap to a STL Map? Do you have suggestions on how I can avoid suplicate keys with the STL Map similar to your fix for the STL Set? Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Frank: I don't know your project, but the way I'd do it I would never _have_ duplicates in the first place because I'd first check if there's already a mapped range in the cache, so I don't quite understand your need for duplicate detection. I've had good results with [tmalloc](http://goog-perftools.sourceforge.net/doc/tcmalloc.html), you could try that as well (no need to change the code, just modify the loader!).

Comment: @Kerrek SB, Thank you for your reply, The multimap we are using uses a char * Pointer as the key,Th multimap key is the pointer to th new memory mapped file region returned by MapViewOfFile. We can't control the pointer address returned by MapViewOfFile, but once in a blue moon it returns the same pointer address twice. We want to avoid to checking for duplicates everytime we insert into the multimap because we don't know the time comlexity of multimap.find().That is why we want to use STL map instead. STL map insert should check to see that a duplicate key is not being inserted. Thank you.

Comment: @KerricK SB, I read your link to tmalloc. How can we get STL to use tmalloc? Thank you for your help?

Comment: @Frank: tmalloc has a functional documentation; basically you just build the thing and set the preload path at load time -- you don't need to change your program at all. I got quite a speedup out of it once in a small (possibly a little artificial) algorithmic program. How can MapViewOfFile return an already mapped address? In any case, I would immediately encapsulate the pointer plus the end pointer into a `Range` object and insert this into the cache set, and upon the next invokation I'd check if the returned address is already in the cache.

Comment: @Kerrick SB, MapViewOfFile can return the same mapped address twice if the mapped address is unmapped using UnMapOfViewOfFile. The challenge is to delete the mapped address from the STL map/multimap after the UnMapViewOfFile. Otherwise, the multimap will have duplicates, tmalloc appears to be for UNIX/LINUX. That is why the documentation talks bout LD_PRELOAD. Is there a tmalloc for Windows. Also, how do you pass the tmalloc memory allocator into the STL set constructor? Thank you.

Comment: @Frank: tmalloc can also be linked against your program, you have to build the Google perftools and just link it in -- it's a replacement for `malloc`, so you don't need any STL allocators (`std::allocator` will already use it automatically). I think I'd make a Map/Unmap framework that would remove ranges from the cache upon unmapping so that duplicates couldn't happen...

Comment: @Kerrek SB, Yes, we need to make a Map/Unmap framework that would remove a char* pointer key from the STL multimap cache as soon as it as unmapped. If we replace tmalloc with malloc, then our entire program would use tmalloc. We would prefer just to use tmalloc for the STL map just like the Fixed Size Block Allocator suite for STL set and map http.warp.povusers.org/FSBAllocator. We are testing it now, I will try to tell you the results tomorrow, Thank you for your help. Your 6% percent improvement is excellent.

Comment: @Kerrek SB, Here are the results for the FSAB Allocator with the std::set<Range , std::less< Range> , FSBAllocator<Range> > ranges_type STL cache with max_size set to 4010 instead of 1. It is 2.93% slower than the 4000 element std::set<Range> optimization which you figured out yesterday. Could you think of a reason of a reason why it may be slower? Thank you.

Comment: @Frank: That's a vague question, how could I possibly know what's going on -- did you profile to figure out exactly which operation is slower? Which data types are you using in both cases? Sorry for also calling mine `Range`, that's confusing now. For a good test of the allocator you should compare the exact same code with the only change being the allocator. Why don't you post the test in your other answer for definiteness.

Comment: @Kerrick SB,I apologize for the vague question. We are profiling the FSAB allocator right now. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: @Kerrick SB, I just accepted your answer. Thank you for all of your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Range { 
    public:   
        explicit Range(int item = 0)
        : mLow(item), mHigh(item), mPtr(0), mMapPtr(0) { }

        Range(int low, int high, char* ptr = 0, char * mapptr = 0, int currMappedLength = 0)
        : mLow(low), mHigh(high), mPtr(ptr), mMapPtr(mapptr), mMappedLength(currMappedLength) { }

        Range(const Range& r)
        : mLow(r.mLow), mHigh(r.mHigh), mMapPtr(r.mMapPtr), mMappedLength(r.mMappedLength) { }

        bool operator<(const Range& rhs) const { return mHigh < rhs.mHigh; }

        int   low()       const { return mLow; }   
        int   high()      const { return mHigh; }
        char* getMapPtr() const { return mMapPtr; }
        int getMappedLength() const { return mMappedLength; }

     private:   
         int mLow;          // beginning of memory mapped file region
         int mHigh;         // end of memory mapped file region 
         char* mMapPtr;     // return value from MapViewOfFile
         int mMappedLength; // length of memory mapped region
};
```

Comment: @Frank: I cleaned up the definition a bit to make it more compact and palatable. Hope that's OK. (We should probably also get rid of the trivial copy constructor, in the spirit of "don't write your own copy constructor".)

Comment: So what does it mean to "cache a range"? Also, how do you prevent nested regions if you only compare by `mHigh`?

Comment: @Kerrek SB, Thank you for cleaning up the definition of a Range. The meaning of "cache a range" is that we try to build a cache of 2000 memory mapped file regions, each with length 131,058 bytes. Each of those 2000 memory mapped file regions is stored in a Range object. When the user requests a pointer memory mapped file region, we look in the cache first. It is faster to retrieve from a STL cache rather than calling MapViewOfFile to obtain a pointer to a file region. Nested regions cannot occur because Range.High = Range.Low + Range.MappedLength. Duplicates are a problem. Thank you.

Comment: @Frank: I could have `Range r1(0, 100), r2(20, 30), r3(0,30);`. Then `r1` and `r2` would be nested, though `r2` would come before `r1` in your ordering, and `r3` and `r2` would actually compare equal. Perhaps lexicographic comparison on both min and max would be more robust.

Comment: Also, do you need to be able to look up a matching range object for any arbitrary pointer in the middle, or just for the ends? E.g. are your requests aligned already or could they be arbitrary?

Comment: @Kerrek SB, We need to able to look up a matching range for any arbitray request which is aligned. Suppose we have have the range Low = 0 High = 131058. Then we need to able to handle pointer request for 54, 128,...256 (any multiple of our matchcode size(i.e 54). Thank you for your reply.

Comment: @Kerrek SB,  "I could have Range r1(0, 100), r2(20, 30), r3(0,30)". We are not sure that a sorted container such a STL multiset would accept this scenario since all the Ranges are sorted by mHigh. So 100, 30, 30 would be be sorted and STL would throw a runtime exception as has happened to us. Thank you.

Comment: @Frank: A multiset would store both `r2` and `r3` (in undetermined order); a set would not -- it would simply not insert the second one, but there's no runtime exception. You just get `false` back from the `insert` call.

Comment: @Kerrek SB, We will have to test this scenario with a test program so see how  the bool operator<(const Range& rhs) const { return mHigh < rhs.mHigh; } handles this case. Thank you for your reply.